# Journal submission: .ins produces .cls?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, journal-publishing

As someone who only uses Overleaf I am running into some trouble with journal submission I am working on. Apparently, I need to convert a .ins file provided in the zip folder with submission material into a .cls. Here are the relevant instructions given in the readme:

- You only need `ejpecp.cls`, `sample.tex`, and `sample.pdf`
- `pdflatex ejpecp.ins` produces `ejpecp.cls`
- Be sure to have `ejpecp.cls` in the same directory (or any dir scanned for `cls`)
- Compile `yourname.tex` with a `pdflatex` engine producing `yourname.pdf`

I am assuming I need to get a compiler software like MacTex and perhaps open the .cls file with it or run a "pdflatex"command, is this right? How can I otherwise *produce*  the .cls? Finally, if I am adamant on using Overleaf afterwards, does the .cls work simply by adding it to the project folder?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ejpecp.cls is already extracted in texlive and installed at Overleaf so you don't need to do anything, just use `\documentclass{ejpecp}` in your main Overleaf document

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: `.ins` identifies an "installation" file that processes a `.dtx` file to produce (usually) a `.cls` or `.sty` file.  The instructions as given are intended for someone to install a package on their local system.  But, as the class file you need is already available at Overleaf, you don't need to do anything special.